# Why are there two colons here? span::before

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is the full line of code I'm looking at, and here is its context: http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/custom-crossbrowser-styling-for-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons

```
input[type="radio"] + span::before { content: ""; display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: url("sprite.png") no-repeat -20px 0; vertical-align: middle; }
```

I have a decent understanding of how this works, but I don't understand why there are two colons, rather than one between span and before.

The before selector, from what I've read should use one colon.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp

On w3c, I can't find any selectors that have two colons, nor can I figure out why span would have a colon following it, in addition to the colon preceding "before".

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: I wouldn't trust anything that is published on w3schools. The SQL tutorial is full of errors.

Comment: No problems, just saw code that I didn't understand. I don't like using anything I don't fully understand for anything important.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's a *pseudo-element*, as defined by the [CSS Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content) spec:

> The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements can be used to describe generated content before or after an element's content.

It is effectively the same as the single-colon syntax defined by the level 2 spec. The level 3 spec introduces an extra colon to differentiate between pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes (which use a single colon).

Both syntaxes will work in newer browsers, but older browsers will not recognise the newer `::` style.

---

For even more detail, you can look at the [grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grammar) from the level 3 spec, which states:

> '::' starts a pseudo-element, ':' a pseudo-class

Answer (score 7):

You can read an article about it [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/before-after-css3/)

But basically it is to differentiate between pseudo classes and pseudo elements. It is a css3 standard to use two colon's for a pseudo element, as oppose to the CSS2 standard of just one.

One or two colons will work as browsers want to cater to both CSS2 and CSS3

Comment: One colon will only work for the CSS1/CSS2 pseudo-elements, not any new ones.

Answer (score 1):

double-colon selectors are pseudo-elements.
single-colon selectors are pseudo-selectors.