# Borders won't show in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I don't know why but the borders won't show in IE 8-9, I haven't got around to checking 10 and upwards. Also the css `:hover` effect doesn't work neither does the modal pop-up. I don't know if there is a work around for IE?

It works perfectly in FF and chrome

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V8H6T/8/)

HTML:

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="chairman"><span class="accent">Chairman / Owner</span><p>Name</p></a>



            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="financemanager"><span class="accent">Finance &<br>
                    Managing Director</span><span>Name</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="financeteam"><span class="accent">Finance
                        Team</span> <span>Name</span><br></a></li>

                        <li><a href="salesdirector"><span class="accent">Sales
                        Director</span><span>Name</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width:100%;
}

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

ul {
    line-height:20px;
}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}

/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #E9E9E9; color: black; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:#06C;
}

span.accent{
    background-color: #113963;
    display: block;
    margin: -5px -10px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Modal CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #F4F4F4;    
}

.close {

    background: #FF2E28;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.close:hover {
    background: #600;
}

.modalDialog + image {
    border:solid 1px black;
}
```

Comment: Borders and hover work on IE >= 9, haven't tried 8 since jsfiddle doesn't work with it.

Comment: Hm, the fiddle works in ie9, but a local copy doesn't

Comment: thanks @CarlMarkham good to know it works on the newer versions. I just hope there is a way to fix it for the older ones

Comment: "Note: In IE there must be declared a  <!DOCTYPE> for the :hover selector to work on other elements than the <a> element."
Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Maybe this explains the difference between the fiddle and the local copy?

Comment: Well the transitions won't work on IE < 10

Comment: @gpgekko so could the correct <!DOCTYPE> possibly fix my problem?

Comment: According to Microsoft, the correct doctype should enable hover effects on any element all the way back to IE7: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848866(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It is working fine in IE11

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools: **http://www.w3fools.com/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore), Internet Explorer < 9 doesn't support the CSS3 `::before` pseudo. If you want to support 8, you'll have to use the CSS2 `:before` pseudo. This would solve the border problem.

The hover problem might be related to declaring the right [doctype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as discussed in the comments.

The problem with the modal is that in IE, it is actually in front of the other elements, just invisible. You'll have to set `display: none` and then place it when it is actually shown:

```
.modalDialog {
    display: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    display: block;
}
```

The reason for this is that the `pointer-events` css attribute [isn't supported in IE](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) (or at least not before 11).
Sadly, completing your modal popup in IE8 using only css will be hard, because the `:target` pseudo [isn't supported in that version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget).

Fiddle with every edit made in this answer: http://jsfiddle.net/V8H6T/12/.

Comment: I've updated my code and fiddle to include the model pop-up problem. if you click on the top "chairman" you will see how it works (but not in ie 9<)

Comment: Ah nice, this hides the pop-up in IE but it still doesnt pop up when I click the link. is this just a case of it not working in the older IE?

Comment: @Adsy The fiddle works for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/V8H6T/9/. Is it any particular IE version that doesn't work for you?

Comment: My IE is 8, do you think it's best to just give up on 8 and upgrade?

Comment: @Adsy I just found out the `:target` pseudo selector isn't supported in IE8: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target. So I'm afraid it won't be possible to make a complete CSS solution for this while supporting IE8.

Comment: Thanks very much with all your help! I know you didn't fix my problem as such but you've helped me enough to get a correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Lol, looked into this alot scratching my head. Turns out the answer is simple,

You are using two colons instead of one:

`ul::before`

should be

`ul:before`

Although there are still some styling errors with this so you will need to fix those. But atleast the borders show up now, right? :P

Comment: By the way, the correct way is with two colons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13400379/148412

Comment: CSS3 is 2 colons, CSS2 is one colon